# asp.net Webforms project looks wrong in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, webforms, internet-explorer-10

We have an existing webforms internet site that we have updated over the years with each new release of visual studio. Currently vs2013 aps.net.

Everything looked fine under IE9, now that we have moved to IE10, controls like dropdown lists, asp buttons, checkbox controls, panels all have problems with padding and margins and alignments and sizes. Regardless if its live, intranet or the local host server in vs2013 in debug mode a lot of controls are skewed vis a vis alignment and padding.

If I set the browser to compatability mode it all looks right.
A lot of things that look correct when I do them in the vs2013 webforms designer don't reneder quite right when I run debug and it launched in IE10.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it ?

thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

The VS 2013 Web Forms Designer usually never gets the design quite right for me, it does the best it can but it's never exactly right...

If not already in place, you may want to look at upgrading the version of the webforms asp.net app to the latest version 4.5 at this point...

Comment: I will see if we can do that. Currently its targeted at .net 4

Comment: Since it's already targeting .net 4 this probably won't fix it.  My project targets 4.0 and works fine in IE 10, I thought you maybe on something older like 2.0...   Instead I would press F12 in IE to open the dev tools and select the elements to see what's going on...  It's probably something with the CSS or HTML:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/bg182326(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0):

Without some actual code it's hard to pinpoint the problems. However if the pages look fine in compatibility mode, you can force IE to switch to compatibility mode using the x-ua-compatible meta tag:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: thanks I will see if that's a option. I didn't post any code because its all fine, perfect under IE9. Whats in the webforms designer renders perfectly correct under IE9 and IE10 compatabilty view. Under native IE10 everything gets skewed a little bit.